# I don't know how to set up a calendar in Vuetify." NaN is not a valid timestamp. It must be a Date, number of seconds since Epoch, I get

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## What I want to solve

I am using Nuxt, Vuetify and Rails to create the calendar. I was able to get the events from the api, but when I click on them I get an error, when I get them in UNIX time ms the error goes away, but this time it doesn't behave as expected. How can I solve this problem?

① This is in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm. In this case, the time is displayed correctly, but an error occurs when clicking on it.

[image]

[image]

② This is the screen at UNIX time ms. The event is in the wrong place, but the click event works correctly. Incidentally, the correct event data is also displayed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same code in the documentation in the function **mouseMove** in the condition

`if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime != null)`

change to

`if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime)`

it works for me.

When i had this error, i checked the value of **this.dragTime** and it was **undefined** and the condition was true so i removed `!= null` and  if **this.dragTime** is **null** or **undefined** never enter to the condition and you never receive a **NaN**